# Очистка карты от маршрута при нажатии кнопки

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api

Нужно построить автомобильный и пешеходный маршруты через google maps по двум точкам. Есть два поля ввода (от и до), и две кнопки (автомобильный маршрут и пеший). Для каждой кнопки есть своя функция. Все работает, только при построении нового маршрута не удаляется старый. Как сделать чтобы перед построением карта очищалась?

```
var myOptions = {
      zoom: 16,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.8374829,21.1518056),
      gestureHandling: 'cooperative',
        scrollwheel: false,
        navigationControl: false,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        scaleControl: false,
        streetViewControl: false,
        zoomControl: true,
    };

    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
    var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
    var mapObject = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);


    function route1(from, to) {      

            var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
            var directionsRequest = {
              origin: from,
              destination: to,
              travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.WALKING,
              unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC
            };
            directionsService.route(
              directionsRequest,
              function(response, status)
              {
                if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK)
                {
                  new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
                    map: mapObject,
                    directions: response
                  });
                }
                else
                  $("#error").append("Unable to retrieve your route<br />");
              }
            );
          }

    function route2(from, to) {

            var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
            var directionsRequest = {
              origin: from,
              destination: to,
              travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING,
              unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC

            };
            directionsService.route(
              directionsRequest,
              function(response, status)
              {
                if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK)
                {
                  new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
                    map: mapObject,
                    directions: response
                  });
                }
                else
                  $("#error").append("Unable to retrieve your route<br />");
              }
            );
  }

  $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#walking button").click(function(event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          route1($("#route-from").val(), $("#route-to").val());
        });

        $("#driving button").click(function(event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          route2($("#route-from").val(), $("#route-to").val());
        });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Пожалуйста  - https://jsfiddle.net/1Lawd8a8/

Необходимо результат выполнения `new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer` присваивать какой нибудь переменной, а перед прокладкой нового маршрута вызвать у этой переменной метод `setMap`, к примеру:

```
    var route = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({ //Добавили маршрут на карту
        map: mapObject,
        directions: response
    });

    route.setMap(null) //Удалили с карты
```

На jsfiddle целиком рабочий пример